# Generating pivot table using apache poi how to allow characters more than 255 in one cell

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to export excel file which contains pivot using apache poi but for one of the cell where data have more than 255 characters, it is getting exported but after opening excel file it is showing me below error:

```
Repaired Records: PivotTable report from /xl/pivotCache/pivotCacheDefinition1.xml part (PivotTable cache)
```

And I using below code to do it.

```
void addRowLabel(XSSFPivotTable pivotTable, Sheet dataSheet, AreaReference areaReference,
            int column, boolean isColumn) {
        try {
            DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter(java.util.Locale.US);
            java.util.TreeSet<String> uniqueItems = new java.util.TreeSet<String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
            for (int r = areaReference.getFirstCell().getRow() + 1; r < areaReference.getLastCell().getRow()
                    + 1; r++) {
                uniqueItems.add(formatter.formatCellValue(dataSheet.getRow(r).getCell(column)));
            }

            // build pivot table and cache
            
                pivotTable.addRowLabel(column);
                CTPivotField ctPivotField = pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields()
                        .getPivotFieldArray(column);
            int i = 0;
            for (String item : uniqueItems) {
                // take the items as numbered items: <item x="0"/><item x="1"/>
                ctPivotField.getItems().getItemArray(i).unsetT();
                ctPivotField.getItems().getItemArray(i).setX((long) i);
                // build a cache definition which has shared elements for those items
                pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheFields()
                        .getCacheFieldArray(column).getSharedItems().addNewS().setV(item);
                i++;
            }


            ctPivotField.setOutline(false); // no outline format
            ctPivotField.setDefaultSubtotal(false); // no subtotals for this field


            if (ctPivotField.getDefaultSubtotal())
                i++; // let one default item be if there shall be subtotals
            for (int k = ctPivotField.getItems().getItemList().size() - 1; k >= i; k--) {
                ctPivotField.getItems().removeItem(k);
            }
            ctPivotField.getItems().setCount(i);
            

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And the record which is not getting not working is something as below:

```
2046 Fidfl HCA-Varofter that see dosfiwrd dpbigeufs norsslettnt priutyits l\u0027abnesce d\u0027acte iotewwuptif de prescription appn de pouiprr lty annlwqr. Melkje en place un dikdfgitif de sqwei des dolocvprs ahjocaghjres indus qer n\u0027ont psd entype faft l\u0027obrtt d\u0027un plan d\u0027action en pltouvrement.
```

If someone knows how to allow string with greater than 255 characters in pivot using poi please help me out on it.

Answer (score 0):

In case if anyone get help from this below line will help to add text with more than 255 characters:

```
pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheFields().getCacheFieldArray(column).getSharedItems().setLongText(true);
```

Full code below:

```
void addRowLabel(XSSFPivotTable pivotTable, Sheet dataSheet, AreaReference areaReference,
        int column, boolean isColumn) {
    try {
        DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter(java.util.Locale.US);
        java.util.TreeSet<String> uniqueItems = new java.util.TreeSet<String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
        for (int r = areaReference.getFirstCell().getRow() + 1; r < areaReference.getLastCell().getRow()
                + 1; r++) {
            uniqueItems.add(formatter.formatCellValue(dataSheet.getRow(r).getCell(column)));
        }

        
            pivotTable.addRowLabel(column);
            CTPivotField ctPivotField = pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields()
                    .getPivotFieldArray(column);
        int i = 0;
        for (String item : uniqueItems) {
            // take the items as numbered items: <item x="0"/><item x="1"/>
            ctPivotField.getItems().getItemArray(i).unsetT();
            ctPivotField.getItems().getItemArray(i).setX((long) i);

            // here you can add that line 


pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheFields()
         .getCacheFieldArray(column).getSharedItems().setLongText(true);
                pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheFields()
.getCacheFieldArray(column).getSharedItems().addNewS().setV(item);
                i++;
        }


        ctPivotField.setOutline(false); // no outline format
        ctPivotField.setDefaultSubtotal(false); // no subtotals for this field


        if (ctPivotField.getDefaultSubtotal())
            i++; // let one default item be if there shall be subtotals
        for (int k = ctPivotField.getItems().getItemList().size() - 1; k >= i; k--) {
            ctPivotField.getItems().removeItem(k);
        }
        ctPivotField.getItems().setCount(i);
        

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```